# Trying to create a physics engine in java from documentary which uses c++

Tags: java, c++, vector, physics, collision

I am just messing around a bit in processing since i know it better than any other language and stumbled up on this website [Custom 2d physics engine](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-basics-and-impulse-resolution--gamedev-6331). So far so good. i am at the point where i have 2 rectangles colliding and i need to resolve the collision. According to the paper i should use the code :

```
void ResolveCollision( Object A, Object B )
{
  // Calculate relative velocity
  Vec2 rv = B.velocity - A.velocity

  // Calculate relative velocity in terms of the normal direction
  float velAlongNormal = DotProduct( rv, normal )

  // Do not resolve if velocities are separating
  if(velAlongNormal > 0)
    return;

  // Calculate restitution
  float e = min( A.restitution, B.restitution)

  // Calculate impulse scalar
  float j = -(1 + e) * velAlongNormal
  j /= 1 / A.mass + 1 / B.mass

  // Apply impulse
  Vec2 impulse = j * normal
  A.velocity -= 1 / A.mass * impulse
  B.velocity += 1 / B.mass * impulse
}
```

This is written in C++ so i would need to port it to java. And here i get stuck on two things. 1: What does the author mean with "normal"? how do i get the "normal"? thing 2 are these 3 lines of code:

```
  Vec2 impulse = j * normal
  A.velocity -= 1 / A.mass * impulse
  B.velocity += 1 / B.mass * impulse
```

He creates a vector wich has only 1 number? j * normal?
I don'really have a clear picture on what exactly happens which does not really benefit me.

Comment: If you don't know what a normal vector is, this isn't really a programming question: you should do some background reading on the maths being modelled. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalVector.html

Comment: normal is defined elsewhere. Search the object or any 'globals'

Comment: "Custom 3d physics engine" -> You link to a page called "How to Create a Custom 2D Physics Engine".

Comment: oh i see, must have been a typo. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

He is probably referring to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_%28geometry%29) as "normal". So normal is a vector with 2 elements since you are referring to a tutorial for 2D physics. And `j*normal` will multiply each element of `normal` with the scalar `j`.

`normal`, `velocity` and `impulse` are vectors with 2 elements for coordinates x, y. From the series of tutorials you are referring to, you can see normal defined [here](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-2d-physics-engine-the-core-engine--gamedev-7493) towards the end.

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" vector at a point on the boundary of a 2D or 3D shape is the vector that is:

1. perpendicular to the boundary at that point;
2. has length 1; and
3. points outward instead of inside the shape

The normal vector is the same all along a straight line (2d) or flat surface (3d), so you will also hear people talk about the "normal" of the line or surface in these cases.

The normal vector is used for all kinds of important calculations in graphics and physics code.

How exactly to calculate the normal vector for a point, line, or surface depends on what data structures you have representing the geometry of your objects.

Comment: Allright, so is this my normal? ` PVector normal = new PVector(-(B.pos.y-A.pos.y),(B.pos.x-A.pos.x));`

Comment: Sorry, that wasn't quite right.  *IF your objects are round*, and those are center positions, then the normal at the point of contact is (B-A)/distance(A,B).  It could be that your physics engine is making this assumption for simplicity.